# Including external handlebars templates?

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm working on a toy EmberJS project and have got to the point where things are becoming really disorganized, so I'm improving my file structure.

I took inspiration from [Discourse's EmberJS application structure](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse), placing my controllers, models, routes, etc in seperate files/folders, but have run into problems when trying to include my handlebars templates back into my project.

What I was doing to re-include my templates is changing my index.html from:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="students">
    <h2>Students:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>{{firstName}} - {{lastName}}<li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="students" src="js/SD/templates/students.js.handlebars"></script>
```

But it's not working.

**How can I include my external handlebars template files successfully for use with my EmberJS application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather use a build tool like [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/) with the corresponding `ember-generator` to get your templates precompiled automatically, or provide your templates directly for the `Ember.TEMPLATES` array, e.g.:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['myTemplate'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('<p>Hello put in here your template</p>');
```

So in your case, add this to your app.js file:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['students'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h2>Students:</h2><ul><li>{{firstName}} - {{lastName}}<li></ul>');
```

So it will be available to ember to be rendered.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks intuitivepixel. I was just experimenting with setting the templates via Ember.TEMPLATES array, but I'd like to keep them in seperate files. I tried doing: Ember.TEMPLATES['students'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile($.get('js/SD/templates/students.js.handlebars')); which doesn't work. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: I'm afraid no. If you want to use separate files then you should go for a build tool like I mentioned otherwise you have to provide the logic of doing so yourself...

Comment: You can also look at Rake Pipeline... Here is an example that uses Grunt.. https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences